# How to refresh rating in adapter using the Cursor Adapter

Tags: android, mysql, android-cursoradapter

It's not duplicate. I saw all answers is Stack.
My problem: I have CommentActivity, where I get Cursor. In CommentCursorAdapter I get values from Database.
In adapter I have two images: Like and Dislike. When I click Like - in database rating incremented. 
TextView rating should show a new rating after pressing. How to do it correctly?

**CommentActivity**

```
public class CommentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String idComment;
private ListView listComments;
private CommentCursorAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_comment);
    listComments = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_comments);

    idComment = getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.ID_KEY);
    getCursorData();
}

private void getCursorData() {
    adapter = new CommentCursorAdapter(this, new CursorLoader(App.getInstance(), idComment).loadInBackground(), 0);
    listComments.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private static class CursorLoader extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    private String idComment;

    public CursorLoader(Context context, String idComment) {
        super(context);
        this.idComment = idComment;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor loadInBackground() {
        return App.getInstance().getDb().rawQuery(
                "SELECT comment._id AS _id, comment.text AS text, user.email AS email, comment.rate FROM comment JOIN user ON comment.userId = user._id WHERE comment.postId = ? ORDER BY _id ASC", new String[]{
                        idComment
                });
    }
}
}
```

**CommentCursorAdapter**

```
public class CommentCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

private TextView commentEmail;
private TextView commentText;
private TextView ratingText;
private ImageView imageViewLike;
private ImageView imageViewDislike;

private static final String ID = "_id";
private static final String EMAIL = "email";
private static final String TEXT = "text";
private static final String RATE = "rate";

public CommentCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, 0);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_comment, viewGroup, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
    commentEmail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.comment_email);
    commentText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.comment_text);
    ratingText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rating_text);
    imageViewLike = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_like);
    imageViewDislike = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_dislike);

    imageViewLike.setTag(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ID)));
    imageViewDislike.setTag(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ID)));

    String email = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(EMAIL));
    String text = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TEXT));
    String rating = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(RATE));

    commentEmail.setText(email);
    commentText.setText(text);
    ratingText.setText(rating);

    imageViewLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.e("like", "click");
            SQLiteStatement statement = App.getInstance().getDb().compileStatement(
                    "UPDATE comment SET rate = rate + 1 WHERE comment._id = ?"
            );
            statement.bindString(1, (String) view.getTag());

            try {
                statement.execute();
            } finally {
                statement.close();
            }

        }
    });

    imageViewDislike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.e("dislike", "click");
            SQLiteStatement statement = App.getInstance().getDb().compileStatement(
                    "UPDATE comment SET rate = rate - 1 WHERE comment._id = ?"
            );
            statement.bindString(1, (String) view.getTag());

            try {
                statement.execute();
            } finally {
                statement.close();
            }

            //swapCursor(cursor);
            //notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: you need to create an interface and call this in activity.. Check out this link for reference http://stackoverflow.com/a/35170004/5746722

Answer (score 0):

There are a some options you can choose from:

1. After updating the rating in the database, you can just reload all data using your loader.
2. You can migrate your database logic to using a `ContentProvider`. If you do it correctly, the provider can notify all loaders that their underlying data has been changed, so they are automatically reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

In your CustomAdapter, you need to put `this.notifyDataSetChanged();` where you are performing operation of the **LIKE** and **COMMENT**.

It's great that you have used CursorAdapter - **that listens for update notifications and reloads the content automatically.**

Hope it will help you.

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged() not work in this case) Thanks

Comment: @ЕгорУрбанович : Can you please tell me from where you are calling notifyDataSetChanged()?

Comment: In imageViewDislike (and like) after block try-finally

Comment: @ЕгорУрбанович : Call it on click of button after you performed your operation

Comment: Please see my code in part imageViewDislike.seotOnClickListener...  I commented out the place where I put notifyDataSetChanged();