# Having challenge in RecyclerView item's onClickListener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an item list which are placed under a RecyclerView. On any item, there a quantity(add or subtract). When add is selected, the quantity should increase one.

[image]

But when i clicked on '+' for the first time, the value of quantity is setting to 1 and soon after resetting to 0, but when i click on second time the value is becoming '1'. Similarly when i click on next time the value is setting to 2 and after a fraction of second it is still getting to 1 and i click on another time the value is becoming 2. Why by first click is not getting recognized? Can someone please help me here?

```
public class ItemListAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemListAdapter.ItemViewHolder>{

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Items> itemsList;
    private OnItemListListner onClick;

    public ItemListAdapter(Context mContext,List<Items> itemsList)
    {
        this.mContext=mContext;
        this.itemsList=itemsList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_details_layout,null);
        return new ItemListAdapter.ItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ItemViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Items items=itemsList.get(position);
        Log.d("onBindViewHolder",items.getItemName());
        holder.itemNameTV.setText(items.getItemName());
        String strItemPrice=mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.Rs)+" "+String.valueOf(items.getItemPrice());
        holder.itemPriceTV.setText(strItemPrice);
        holder.itemDescTV.setText(items.getItemDescription());

        Glide.with(mContext).load(items.getItemImagePath()).into(holder.imageView);

        holder.itemAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int intCurrentQuantity=Integer.valueOf(holder.itemQuantity.getText().toString());
                intCurrentQuantity+=1;
                Log.d("myQuantity",String.valueOf(intCurrentQuantity));
                holder.itemQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(intCurrentQuantity));
                notifyItemChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });


        holder.itemNameTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onClick.onItemListClick(position);
            }
        });
        holder.itemPriceTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onClick.onItemListClick(position);
            }
        });
        holder.itemDescTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onClick.onItemListClick(position);
            }
        });
        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onClick.onItemListClick(position);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemsList.size();
    }

    public void SetOnClick(OnItemListListner onClick)
    {
        this.onClick=onClick;
    }

    class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView imageView;
        TextView itemNameTV,itemPriceTV,itemDescTV,itemQuantity,itemSubtract,itemAdd;

        public ItemViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemImageView);
            itemNameTV=itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemNameTextView);
            itemPriceTV=itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemPriceTextView);
            itemDescTV=itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemDescritionTextView);
            itemQuantity=itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemQuantity);
            itemSubtract=itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtractQuantity);
            itemAdd=itemView.findViewById(R.id.addQuantity);
        }
    }

    public interface OnItemListListner{
        void onItemListClick(int position);
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android - Unable to increment or decrement value from list item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35061528/android-unable-to-increment-or-decrement-value-from-list-item)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recycler view recycles the views on scroll and resets its content, so you have to persist the quantity `qty` variable. You can do it by two ways

1. Store quantity inside your **Items** model.
2. Persist quantity in seperate `HashMap` as `item.getId()` as key and `qty` as value.

then get and set from the model object or hashmap.

Comment: the second approach helped me. Thanks for insights.

Comment: Basically, the worse one :D

Answer (score 1):

Reviewd your code and then after i'm just agreed with Harsh's Answer 
there is a two way to set your adapter. most commonly used Model for storing and retriving data.

You need to create a one model class and and set data first into the model then after get data from model and set into your adapter / notify your adapter.

You need to create one variable in model class like below snippet:

```
public class Item {
    String mQty = "";
    public String getmQty() {
        return mQty;
    }

    public void setmQty(String mQty) {
        this.mQty = mQty;
    }
}
```

Helpful Answer: [Click Me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35061528/android-unable-to-increment-or-decrement-value-from-list-item)

Comment: This answer would also help, but this can also be just done with HashMap than creating a separate class as far as my need at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

you should have the quantity property in Item model class and have to follow the code I added below.

```
holder.itemAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int quantity = item[getAdapterPosition()].quantity;
quantity = quantity +1;
item[getAdapterPosition()].setQuantity(quantity);
notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    });
```

Thanks.I am sure this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yeah, at this moment, i am not planning to save the quantity in Item model, because any point user will be displayed with 0 quantity and + and - symbols for all items. When clicked on these symbols, we need to update the quantity. So as Harsh said above, i followed HashMap to store position and current quantity. When user adds or subtract, the quantities are updated from the HashMap.

Comment: ok no issue that is unto your logic dear you can also filter to show or not to show the quantity but that depends on your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Check updated code

```
 holder.itemAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int intCurrentQuantity=Integer.valueOf(holder.itemQuantity.getText().toString());
                ++intCurrentQuantity; //use this    
                Log.d("myQuantity",String.valueOf(intCurrentQuantity));
                holder.itemQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(intCurrentQuantity));
                notifyItemChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
```

Comment: the value is not getting updated. Logically also the above may not work. Can you please explain what it will change if prefix the increment than what i used?